# Latex: Wrong reference number

Tags: latex, reference

I have 6 figures in my .tex file. Wherever I put a reference to the 6th image, in the pdf I get Figure1.**5** instead of Figure1.**6** (1 less) but upon clicking the link I go to the right figure Figure1.6.

Similarly, when I refer to 5th image, in the pdf I get Figure1.**4** instead of Figure1.**5**, once again when I click the link I go to Figure1.5.

Same goes to a reference to 4th image, I get 1 less (1.3 instead of 1.4) in the pdf. Same with 1.3, I get 1.2.

**But** for 1.2 I get exactly 1.2 and 1.1 I get 1.1.

Why is this happening? I thought it was due to `\caption` and `\label` order in the figure, but I have already verified that they are in the right order. So I don't think so that it is that problem.

Help!

---

### Code for figures from 1.1 to 1.6

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.1a} \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{Images/Figure001.png}}
        \hspace{1.0mm}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.1b} \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{Images/Figure002.png}}
    \end{center}
        \textit{\caption{abcd...........xyz}}
    \label{figure1.1}
\end{figure}
```

%---------------------------------%

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.2a} \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{Images/Figure004.png}}
        \hspace{1.0mm}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.2b} \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{Images/Figure005.png}}
    \end{center}
        \textit{\caption{abcd...........xyz}}
    \label{figure1.2}
\end{figure}
```

%---------------------------------%

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.3a} \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Images/Figure006.png}}
        \hspace{2.0mm}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.3b} \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Images/Figure007.png}}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.3c} \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{Images/Figure008.png}}
    \end{center}
        \textit{\caption{abcd...........xyz}}
    \label{figure1.3}
\end{figure}
```

%---------------------------------%

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.4a} \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{Images/Figure009a.png}}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.4b} \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Images/Figure010.png}}
        \hspace{2.0mm}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.4c} \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Images/Figure011.png}}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.4d} \includegraphics[width=0.403\textwidth]{Images/Figure012.png}}
        \hspace{2.0mm}
        \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.4e} \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Images/Figure013.png}}
    \end{center}

\textit{\caption{abcd...........xyz}}
\label{figure1.4}

\end{figure}
```

%---------------------------------%

```
  \begin{figure}
            \begin{center}
                \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.5a} \includegraphics[width=0.403\textwidth]{Images/Figure014a.png}}
                \hspace{2.0mm}
                \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz}]{\label{fig:Fig1.5b} \includegraphics[width=0.403\textwidth]{Images/Figure014b.png}}
            \end{center}

            \begin{center}
            \subfigure[\textit{abcd...........xyz]{\label{fig:Fig1.5c} \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Images/Figure015.png}}
            \end{center}

        \textit{\caption{abcd...........xyz}}
        \label{figure1.5}

        \end{figure}
```

%---------------------------------%

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.80\textwidth]{Images/Figure015a.png}
    \textit{\caption{abcd...........xyz}}
\end{center}
    \label{figure1.6}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for the relevant figures (e.g., 1.1, and 1.4)?

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables, I have edited the question, added the code for the figures.

Comment: The problem might be subfigure-specific.  Can you reproduce a minimal not-working example /without/ sub-figures?

Comment: since 1.1 and 1.2 seem to be working fine, it seems like the problem originate from 1.3. It's possible that figure 1.3 did not get labeled properly and so latex did not add it to the figure counter and continued from the 4th figure being 1.3. Since the label name is independent of the internal figure counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. The problem started with this step - I wanted to have italicized captions, which out of my intuition, I was doing it this way:

```
\textit{\caption{abcd...........xyz}}
```

For all my captions I have the `\textit` enclosing the `\caption{}`, this was what was causing the problem. I don't understand why.

So I removed all of them and the references now work perfectly.

But I still wanted the italics captions.

So, I did this, I gave options to the package directly

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=it, labelfont=bf}
```

Here, `font=it` italics the entire caption including the label and `labelfont=bf` bolds only the label.

But this **ONLY** italicized the captions of a figure, for the captions of a sub-figure I had to once again give options to sub-figure package

```
\usepackage[bf, it, IT]{subfigure}
```

Where `bf` and `it` options bolds and italics the label and `IT` option will only italics the text.

Thats it, the problem is solved!

Comment: This solution just helped me with a similar problem where I had naively used `itshape` to get letters that looked like they did in equations elsewhere. Replacing these commands with regular `$...$` fixed the numbering issue.

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether the reference to figure 2 is set correctly.

Comment: I have added the code for the figures, can you kindly take a look at them once?

Comment: Looks good. Try to strip everything of your file in order to isolate the problem. That works most of the time for me.